# what is the expectation value of a norm of a random variable from the standard normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value

Let's suppose $\zeta_k \in \mathbb{R}^p$ is a random variable from a normal distribution with mean zero and 1 standard deviation. why $E[|| \zeta_k ||^2]=p$?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Are the components independent?

Comment: Thank you, yes they are independent.

Comment: The expectation, $E(\eta_k)^2$, is 1 and you can sum them since they are independent and since there are $p$ of them, the result is $p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the components are independent, it means that the squared $L_2$ norm of $\zeta$ has a $\chi^2_k$ distribution, which is the sum of squared independent standard normal variables.

The expected value of a $\chi^2_k$ variable is $k$.

In more generality, we do not even require the independence.

$$
\mathbb E\bigg[\vert\vert\zeta\vert\vert^2\bigg] = \mathbb E\bigg[
\sum_{i=1}^k \zeta_i^2
\bigg] = \sum_{i=1}^k\mathbb E\bigg[
\zeta_i^2
\bigg] = \sum_{i=1}^k 1 = k
$$